# Make return-type of a function dependant on parameter-type?

Tags: typescript

I have a simple function

```
function fn<T = any>(param1?: X): T {
}
```

What I want to do is, make the return-type of `fn` dependant on `param1`.

If `param1` is undefined -> return `T | undefined`

If not -> return `T`

Is that possible in Typescript?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [function overloading](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/functions.html#overloads) for this:

```
function fn<T>(): T | undefined;
function fn<T, X>(param1: X): T;
function fn<T, X>(param1?: X): T | undefined { 
    // dummy implementation
    if (param1) {
        return {} as T;
    }

    return undefined;
};

const foo = fn<string>(); // string | undefined
const bar = fn<string, number>(1); // string
```

Don't forget to turn *strictNullChecks* on.